# Cucumber Routing Results in ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, cucumber, view, actionview

So I am trying to set up a cucumber test that visits the will visit the course index page, and then it clicks on a course to go to that specific course's show page. What ends up happening, however, is that everything goes as it should (hits the show action in the course controller, shows the right @student object that it should redirect to once the path is activated), but it actually doesn't do that. It hits the courses controller instead, and results in a `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"courses", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id] (ActionView::Template::Error)` error message.

Here's my setup:

#### admin_view_steps.rb

```
When(/^I select a student$/) do
  click_on "#{@student.first_name} #{@student.last_name}"
end

Then(/^I should see their information$/) do
  expect(page).to have_content(@student.first_name)
end
```

#### admin_view.feature

```
Scenario: See Individual Student Page
    Given I am logged in as a flatiron employee
    When  I visit the students page
    And   I select a student
    Then  I should see their information
```

#### courses_controller.rb

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @courses = Course.all
  end

  def new
    @course = Course.new
  end

  def create
    @course = Course.new(course_params)
    if @course.save
      flash[:notice] = "Course has successfully been saved."
      redirect_to course_path(@course)
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error! Course was not successfully saved."
      redirect to new_course_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

#### students_controller.rb

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @students = Student.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
    if @student.save
      flash[:notice] = "Student form successfully submitted."
      redirect_to students_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to process your request."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    Student.update(@student, student_params)
    redirect_to student_path(@student)
  end

  def destroy
    @student.destroy
    redirect_to courses_path
  end

  private

  def set_student
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  end

  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(removed_attributes)
  end
end
```

#### routes.rb

```
Registrar::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :courses do
    resources :students, controller: :courses_students, only: [:new, :create, :show]
  end

  resources :students

  devise_for :users, :path_names => { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }, :controllers => {
    :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks",
    :sessions => "sessions"
  }

    root 'pages#landing'
end
```

#### students/show.html.erb

```
<br><br>
<%= @student.first_name %>
<%= @student.last_name %><br>
<br>
<%= link_to "Back to Course", course_path(@student.course) %> 
<%= link_to "Students", students_path %>
<br>
```

#### students/index.html.erb

```
<br><br>
<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <%= link_to "#{student.first_name} #{student.last_name}", student_path(student) %><br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Landing Page", root_path %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!